# How to display latest 3 data from google sheet

Tags: arrays, post, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I am doing a telegram bot to retrieve all my expenses. I am doing a features to retrieve the latest 3 expenses.

This is the portion to list my expenses and it will show all the expenses

```
function doPost(e) {
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); 
var ssId = "<< ssId >>";
var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName("Sheet1");
if (contents.callback_query) {
    var id = contents.callback_query.from.id;
    var data = contents.callback_query.data;
    if (data == 'expenses') {
      var expenses = [];
      var lr = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
      
      for(var i = 6; i <=lr; i++) { //my expenses record start from cell A6
        var date = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
        
        var month = new Array();
        month[0] = "January";
        month[1] = "February";
        month[2] = "March";
        month[3] = "April";
        month[4] = "May";
        month[5] = "June";
        month[6] = "July";
        month[7] = "August";
        month[8] = "September";
        month[9] = "October";
        month[10] = "November";
        month[11] = "December"; 
        
        var formatedDate = date.getDate() + " " + (month[date.getMonth()]) + " " + date.getFullYear();     
        var item = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
        var price = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
        
        expenses.push("\n" + formatedDate + " | " + item + " | " + price );
        var expenseList = expenses.join("\n");
      }
      sendText(id, decodeURI( "Here your last expenses: " + "\n" + expenseList ));
    }
```

---

```
My google sheet looks like
Date        | Expenses | Price
03 Mar 2020 | Cookies  | 6
04 Mar 2020 | Bread    | 5
05 Mar 2020 | Drinks   | 7
06 Mar 2020 | Chocolate| 8
07 Mar 2020 | Buns     | 7
08 Mar 2020 | Sweets   | 7
```

Comment: You question is poor at the moment, you code is incomplete, you have tags missing, and it isn't formatted right. As you are a new user, welcome and please read [how-top-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already pushing each expense into the array `expenses`,  why not use the [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method, to create a new Array with your selected a portion of `expenses`.

For your example, the last line could be changed to:

> `sendText(id, decodeURI( "Here your last expenses: " + "\n" + expenses.slice(-3).join("\n") ));`

And you can do without the `expenseList` variable.

Comment: `expenseList` is a string and not a array.